# Missing MSVCR90D.dll

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm writing a C++ program (32 bit) that uses [SFML 1.6](http://www.sfml-dev.org/). The release build can be compiled and run without problems whereas the debug build also compiles without problems but can't be run. [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) shows that the debug version of SFML requires a MSVCR90D.dll and a MSVCP90D.dll. Both files can't be found on my hard drive. I didn't compile SFML myself (I've downloaded the binaries) and didn't notice before that it was compiled with Visual Studio 2008 whereas I am using VS 2010 Express. So I thought downloading the VS 2008 redistributables would fix the problem but it didn't. Now I am not sure if using libraries that were compiled with an older compiler version is a good idea in general.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Which redistributable do I need to install to get those missing DLLs?

PS: I am using Win7 64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately those are the VS2008 debug runtime DLLs (the 'D' on the end). You're not officially allowed to distribute them.

Note that mixing C++ between compiler versions is dangerous. Your options are probably

1. get hold of the source and rebuild it yourself with VS2010 (this will also allow you to debug into it which can be useful for understanding / discovering issues with the library)
2. install VS2008 C++ (express or not) and work with that instead.

I was going to suggest getting the builder to re-build as release for you, but there's still the 2008 vs 2010 problem.

Answer (score 1):

For your main question, Rup is right. Regarding mixing VS2008/VS2010 runtime, let say that:

- `libA.dll` is ABI (link time) dependent on VS2008 DLL runtime;
- `libB.dll` is ABI dependent on VS2010 DLL runtime.

In my experience, it's safe in using **release** builds of both `libA.dll` and `libB.dll` in your VS projects as long as:

- you are correctly dinamically linking `libA` and `libB` (selecting the correct `libA.lib` and `libB.lib` in the linker input);
- using `libA`, `libB` **headers** doesn't create an ABI mismatch at run-time, depending on mixed VS2008/VS2010 headers (for example STL).

For example:

```
// libA.h

#include <vector>  

class LibAClass
{
private:
    // This is unsafe, warning c4251: users of libA may allocate a different size
    // than expected for the vector. The code can perfectly compile but at runtime
    // it can cause problems (verified myself)
    std::vector _list;

    // The following is safe as long as users of libA are not required to
    // deal directly with *_listp
    std::vector *_listp;
};
```

Comment: The usual one that'll bite you, though, is mixing objects allocated between the two: with two different runtimes with two different allocation heaps you need to make sure that only objects allocated by the 2008 code are freed by the 2008 code etc. There's also any minor C++ ABI changes that might exist between versions - I don't know if there actually are with VC++ although this does happen between some GCC versions as they refine / debug their ABI and name-mangling schemes. Release / debug ought not matter.

Comment: You are correct. Read also my edits. Mangling is also a big problem but I think VS2010/VS2008 are 100% (or something very close) compatible.  What I want to say that, if you know what you are doing, mixing dependency on VS2008/VS2010 runtimes is reasonably safe.

Comment: Mangling isn't really what you need to worry about, though: if they've changed the mangling scheme then they've almost certainly changed the ABI in a breaking way. Silent ABI changes are more of a problem.